# Count the numbers of projects

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets; Sheet1 contains different building names (repetition) and Sheet2 contains a list of the building names. I will like to count the number of building in sheet1 and show them in sheet2.

Currently, I'm using workbook function COUNTIF. How can i do it if there's a new building added in sheet1? (VBA or workbook function is fine)

Comment: How about a simple PivotTable?

Comment: Yes I tried, just sourcing for another way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dynamic named range in sheet 1 (for the list of buildings), and then refer to the named range in your countif function in sheet2.

For more details on how dynamic named ranges work, have a look at this:-

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Another alternative would be to use the whole column that contains the building names, as your countif function will only return a value for cells that contain the criteria specified in the function.  It might look something like this:-

=countif(Sheet1!A:A,"building a")  <--this would search for all cells containing 'building a' in column A of Sheet 1

Answer (score 0):

As you use either dynamic range or `A:A` range on `CounIF()` it works only as long as you do not have any blank cells within the range. Please know that. In such cases you are better off with a `pivot table` and pointing to pivot table's total cells accordingly.

Or if you still prefer to use `CountIf()` in blank cells case, you may apply `conditional formatting` to fill the blanks with some text/string. Don't forget conditional formatting contributes to slowing down your sheet performance. Or you could wrap CountIf() with an `IF` condition.